# Create a custom filled Svg column

Tags: html, svg

Does anyone know how to create a SVG depicting a column with a filling of my choice?
For example how to create a svg like this without having to create manually all the filling lines?:

[image: column]

Comment: This is what <pattern> is for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns

Answer (score 1):

You could create an image (for example) 10x10 with a red background en a diagonal stroke and repeat the image?

Called a pattern

[image: Pattern explaination]

Here a small example

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 100, 1000);
var rectangle = paper.rect(0, 0, 100, 1000);
rectangle.attr({
    "fill": "url(your/image.jpg)"
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YhDsD/

Comment: Thank you for the reply but the pattern thing was what i was actually looking for.